# Server Client Communication Python

Tags: python, sockets, client

**Server**

```
import socket
import sys
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host= 'VAC01.VACLab.com'
port=int(2000)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(1)

conn,addr =s.accept()

data=s.recv(100000)

s.close
```

**CLIENT**

```
import socket
import sys

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host="VAC01.VACLab.com"
port=int(2000)
s.connect((host,port))
s.send(str.encode(sys.argv[1]))

s.close()
```

I want the server to receive the data that client sends.

I get the following error when i try this

**CLIENT Side**

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Client.py", line 21, in 
    s.send(sys.argv[1])
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

**Server Side**

File "Listener.py", line 23, in 
    data=s.recv(100000)
socket.error: [Errno 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed bec
ause the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a
sendto call) no address was supplied

Comment: I think you may have to convert the `str` to `bytes`.

Comment: Do i do this str.encode(sys.argv[1]) ?? i did that ,the errors have stopped but the data is not transferring.

Comment: Are you still having trouble?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the server, you use the *listening* socket to receive data. It is only used to accept new connections.

change to this:

```
conn,addr =s.accept()

data=conn.recv(100000)  # Read from newly accepted socket

conn.close()
s.close()
```

Comment: Still giving the same error at the client side. The server error got resolved.

Comment: but their are [`recv()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv) and [`send()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send) methods on `socket` object.

Answer (score 3):

Your line `s.send` is expecting to receive a stream object. You are giving it a string. Wrap your string with BytesIO.

Comment: Do i do this str.encode(sys.argv[1]) ?? i did that ,the errors have stopped but the data is not transferring.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Python are you using? From the error message, I guess you are unintentionally using Python3. You could try your program with Python2 and it should be fine.

Comment: Vinod - Try it with Python2 then to know the difference.

Answer (score -1):

try to change the client socket to:

```
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
```