# Encounter socket connection error in python

Tags: python, sockets

This is the **error** received:

```
raw_data, adrr = conn.recvfrom(65535)
socket.error: [Errno 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied.
```

The **code** written:

```
while True:
        raw_data, adrr = conn.recvfrom(65535)
        dest_mac, src_mac, eth_proto, data= ethernet_frame(raw_data)
        print('\nEthernet Frame:')
        print('Destination:{},source:{}, Protocol:{}'.format(dest_mac, src_mac, eth_proto))
```

Comment: It seems like you're getting the reason in the error.  Perhaps it would be useful to post the connection object as well.  My guess is the error is occurring there.

Comment: We need to code where you created the `conn` object.

Comment: ok. here it is:

Comment: conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
conn.bind(('', 9999))

Comment: @Noah okay..thats exactly what the problem is. you should not say
`conn.recvfrom()` the socket object. Instead it should be from where you accept data. Example : `conn,addr =s.accept()

data=conn.recv(100000)` Same example is given in the below link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005851/server-client-communication-python

Comment: have than the correction but still not working. other error coming.

Comment: return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted